# How to cache entire webpage in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I want to load a webpage when user connected to network  and store it offline(including with images/resources). If the user not connected to any network then i should load the previously stored webpage. I have tried `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url` and `NSString stringWithContentsOfURL` but these stores only html content not the resources. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). If you do not want to to use that project (it is no longer active) you can look into the code and what it does. Look at "[how to cache a whole web page with images in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696151/how-to-cache-a-whole-web-page-with-images-in-ios)" for more info as well.

Answer (score 0):

Write this data into file using:

```
-(void)writeDataToFile:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    if(filename==nil)
    {
        DLog(@"FILE NAME IS NIL");
        return;
    }
    // the path to write file
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",filename]];
    /*NSData *writeData;
     writeData=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:pArray]; */
    NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(!filePath)
    {
        //DLog(@"File %@ doesn't exist, so we create it", filePath);
        [fm createFileAtPath:filePath contents:self.mRespData attributes:nil];
    }
    else 
    {
        //DLog(@"file exists");
        [self.mRespData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

    NSMutableData *resData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.mRespData=resData;
    [resData release];
}
```

and load it next time.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question. It's not about how to store data, but about how to download everything of website and store it.

Comment: I don't want to store any data, but the questioner seems to ... The question - as I understood - is: How to save *everything* of *any* website for later offline usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution is this - "Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide", https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Only if you are making an app with HTML5 and webview,  didn't test this method yet so far, so it might work.

Comment: This is about offline storage, if you are the web developer, but the question is how to store *any* website for offline usage.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, You are right, only if we are making an app with webview and HTML5 as well, HTML5 can do this job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is one-line-solution like `myWebView.cache4Offline = YES;` , but I fear as long as you don't have access to the website's code (i.e. if you want to make *any* website available offline inside your app), you have to program this on your own. Thinking about it, it doesn't seem so difficult:

1. Scan the html string for image urls (and everything else you need)
2. Download those resources from the internet using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` (maybe a little annoying, because of relative/absolute URLs)
3. Save data to file with NSData writeToFile:options:error:
4. Replace URL in HTML with filePath from 3. (OR, better use a convention for converting *their* URLs in *your* file-URLs)

Hope it helps

Comment: This solution would work, except that you have no way to replace the URL with the filepath in hTML, since the filePath points to NSData not a .png image