# Get full-text articles from RSS Feed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Hello I am using GDataXML to parse RSS Feeds.

However most of todays feeds doesn't show the full text article. So most of the times I end up with just a tiny piece of the whole thing. 
I see this feature in a lot of iPhone and iPad readers - it kinda fetches the article from the web and put it in full text.

So how do i do that?

My idea is this - the root element starts with the start of the article.
So if the root element have [article]
i need to go to the website, fetch the html code between the starting divs, and then display it in my app.

So how do i get the code between those divs? regular expressions or what? I want example thanks.

And finally how do i display images after I get the full article in html format?

Thanks guys and regards.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out on this, or just give up and go another route?

Answer (score 0):

use MWFeedParser you will get RSS Feeds in

**identifier, title, link, date, updated, summary, content, enclosures**

Comment: No. Doesn't do what i need, and it surely doesn't get the full text. Nor the enclosures.

Answer (score 0):

I use MWFeedParser as well, because it will get all the elements of a feed entry, but you are correct that it will not do a "deep dive" into all of the links in the feed entry.

If you want to bring in the full content from the link, and the full content from the enclosures (such as audio or video from a podcast), you are basically talking about saving the web page for offline viewing.  For a full html page, you would have to save that HTML, plus crawl the whole page and save the images, and change the path of those images so that you would be able to load it offline.  It's not really the job of the RSS applications to save HTML content for offline use, but to get the elements of the RSS feed.  Once you have all the links you want to save for offline use, you need to provide the code that will take a URL and save it offline.

I did a search for `ios save html offline` and found this post which seems pretty positive using [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to save a page offline: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6698854/1072068.  I would recommend you try using something like that once you get the parts of the rss feed entry from MWFeedParser.